# How do I defeat the cyclops in Dark Messiah?

Tags: dark-messiah-of-might-and-magic

I'm getting my ass kicked by the Cyclops in Chapter 5.  I can wait for him to attack and hit him in the eye when he's bent down but it's sucking up all my health potions. There's GOT to be a better way!

Comment: *POTENTIAL SPOLER* It's been quite a long time since I've played the game, so just to be clear, just which chapter is chapter 5? Are you talking about the cyclops you fight in the cave/ruins (the one that busts through the wall) or the one you fight in some city later on? (or perhaps it's a different one I don't remember altogether).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that makes this easier is to drop the statue on the other end of the room on him. Kicking it into him after it's fallen is also a lot more effective than it should be.

I've also found that stabbing (forward and backward strong attack with a sword) is more effective, and sometimes results in a one-hit kill (with a fairly weak sword, without adrenaline).

Of course, this cyclops *is* completely optional. You can also come back after you place the Shantiri crystal -- if you visited a certain secret area earlier, you can smelt a very powerful sword later in the chapter.

Comment: Very nicely written.

Answer (score 1):

If you find the Endless Quiver earlier on in the level, you can just stick arrows in his eye from the corridor the goblins came from.